# is it worth defragging an iPod

Tags: ipod, defragment, maintenance

Essentially my 5G iPod was cutting tracks off and generally misbehaving.
So I did the following:

1) Use [Diskwarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/Diskwarrior/index.html) - heavy directory fragmentation which it fixed;

2) Use [iDefrag](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iDefrag.php) - some fragmentation but it kept halting as it couldn't move files;

3) Try to write out drive with Disk Utility - got a warning from DU so gave up before I started;

4) Completely restored using iTunes;

5) Reran Diskwarrior - still heavy directory fragmentation;

6) Reran iDefrag, still fragmentation although limited to two bands;

The iPod is much quicker to traverse menus and no more track skipping.

My question is this - is defragging worth it or does the heat generated by the process kill the drive and make it a self-defeating process.  Anyone have any metrics/ figures?
Clearly it's a bad idea for solid state drives like the nano & touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a complete restore basically does the same thing as what you're trying to do with a defrag.  It wipes the drive clean then writes all files back.  Since all free space is consolidated, All the files' contents are contiguous.

Heat is bad for drives, but I don't think the heat would cause much harm, honestly.

Comment: So you'd think - but according to iDefrag and Diskwarrior that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is more a case of OCD(!), unless you have a serious problem with your iPod, refreshing is probably more sensible.